# jquery очистить соседний textarea по клику на кнопку

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код

```
<div class="form">
   <p align="center">
      <div class="message2add">
         <textarea class="textMessage2"></textarea>
      </div>
      <button class="addMessage2">Добавить второе сообщение</button>
   </p>
</div>

<div class="form">
   <p align="center">
      <div class="message2add">
         <textarea class="textMessage2"></textarea>
      </div>
      <button class="addMessage2">Добавить второе сообщение</button>
   </p>
</div>

<div class="form">
   <p align="center">
      <div class="message2add">
         <textarea class="textMessage2"></textarea>
      </div>
      <button class="addMessage2">Добавить второе сообщение</button>
   </p>
</div>
```

Кнопка с классом `addMessage2` находится в `div` с классом `form` Как пре клике на нее очистить `textarea`с классом `textMessage2` в том диве где сама кнопка.

Пробовал так

```
$('html').on('click','.addMessage2',function (){
  $('.textMessage2').val(" ");
});
```

Но тогда очищаются все `textarea` а нужно очистить тот `textarea` в котором диве сама кнопка и `textarea`.

PS: Код изменить не могу. Уже очень много чего привязал к нему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С помощью функции `siblings` ищем соседний элемент, а там обращаемся к дочернему `textarea`

```js
$('html').on('click', '.addMessage2', function() {
  $(this).siblings('.message2add').children('.textMessage2').val(' ');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form">
  <p align="center">
    <div class="message2add">
      <textarea class="textMessage2"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button class="addMessage2">Добавить второе сообщение</button>
  </p>
</div>

<div class="form">
  <p align="center">
    <div class="message2add">
      <textarea class="textMessage2"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button class="addMessage2">Добавить второе сообщение</button>
  </p>
</div>

<div class="form">
  <p align="center">
    <div class="message2add">
      <textarea class="textMessage2"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button class="addMessage2">Добавить второе сообщение</button>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, я читал читал о siblings и так и не разобрался с ним. Ведать пора уже отдыхать.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(_ => {
  $('.form').on('click', '.addMessage2', function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.textMessage2').val('');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form">
   <p align="center">
      <div class="message2add">
         <textarea class="textMessage2"></textarea>
      </div>
      <button class="addMessage2">Добавить второе сообщение</button>
   </p>
</div>

<div class="form">
   <p align="center">
      <div class="message2add">
         <textarea class="textMessage2"></textarea>
      </div>
      <button class="addMessage2">Добавить второе сообщение</button>
   </p>
</div>

<div class="form">
   <p align="center">
      <div class="message2add">
         <textarea class="textMessage2"></textarea>
      </div>
      <button class="addMessage2">Добавить второе сообщение</button>
   </p>
</div>
```